# Sample Splint options file for Windows

Tags: c, embedded, iar, splint

I am trying to make splint work with an embedded project I am working on. I was wondering if there was a sample `.splintrc` options file to which I can add my own options/configuration to simplify the whole process. I am using IAR workbench for compiling and building the project and want to integrate splint with the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an options file that tries to cover some of the MISRA-C 2004 rules:

```
#-hints
#-forcehints
 -linelen 120
 -parenfileformat
 +quiet

 -booltype  bool
 -booltrue  true
 -boolfalse false

 -standard
 +strictlib

# the flags commented out below are switched on by default or the
# '-standard' shortcut.

 +ansi89limits
#+boolops
#+casebreak
#-charint
 +cppnames
 +declundef
 +elseifcomplete
#+evalorder
 +exportheader
 +exportheadervar
#+exportlocal
 -externalnamelen 31
 +fcnmacros
#+firstcase
#-floatdouble
 +forblock
#+gnuextensions
 +ifblock
#-ignorequals
#-ignoresigns
#+imptype
#+incompletetype
#+incondefs
#+initsize
 -internalnamelen 31
 +isoreserved
 +isoreservedinternal
#-longintegral
#-longunsignedintegral
#+macroassign
#+macrofcndecl
#+macroparams
#+macroparens
#+macrostmt
 -maintype
#-matchanyintegral
#-modfilesystem
#+namechecks
#+nestcomment
#+noeffect
 +noparams
#+noret
 +oldstyle
#+predassign
#+predboolint
 +protoparammatch
#-protoparamname
 +ptrarith
#+realcompare
 +redecl
#+redef
 -relaxquals
#-relaxtypes
 +retval
#+shadow
#+shiftimplementation
#+shiftnegative
 +slashslashcomment
#+stackref
#+sysunrecog
#+type
#+unreachable
#+unrecog
#+unrecogdirective
#+usedef
#+usevarargs
 +whileblock
```

Source:
http://www.cs.virginia.edu/pipermail/splint-discuss/2007-March/000923.html